# width and height in presentPopoverFromRect?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios4, uipopovercontroller

In **`presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:`**, method of **`UIPopoverViewController`**, for "**`presentPopoverFromRect`**", what I have understood is that "**`x`**" and "**`y`**" are where it will point its anchor but what "**`width`**" and "**`height`**" parameter will do?

I am playing with them by setting different values and result is very confusing.

Comment: The anchor points to a rect, not to a point. Tho you could specify 0 for width and height.

Comment: No, you can't specify 0, or you get warned with _the rect passed in to this method must have non-zero width and height. This will be an exception in a future release_ But you can specify FLT_MIN.

Answer (score 4):

Call the `setPopoverContentSize:animated:` method on your `UIPopoverController` object, and that will set the height and width of your popover.

The position of the UIPopoverController is controlled by the `presentPopoverFromRect:inView:permittedArrowDirections:animated:` method.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was wondering if you can tell me what "width" and "height" are doing in "presentPopoverFromRect" when you can set the height and width of the popover in "setPopoverContentSize:animated:"

Comment: I'm really not sure what those controls do. I'd experimented with them, but didn't see any changes made when I built and ran the application in the simulator or on my iPad. If the answer was helpful, please click the green check mark to say I answered! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is confusing, and the Apple documentation doesn't make it any clearer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html

ott started you in the right direction... presentPopoverFromRect uses a CGRect object as its anchor.  What I learned by reading other posts here, is that the CENTER of that rectangle is used as the anchor position for the UIPopoverController, not its x,y coordinates.  Although, I'm uncertain whether that varies based on permittedArrowDirections (I'm using zero for that).  All the apple documentation says is "The rectangle in view at which to anchor the popover window."

To make it operate nearly like point coordinates, I've been using width=1 and height=1 for my anchor rect size.

Hope that helps!

Comment: For a small rectangle centered in the view, you could go with `CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds) - 1.f, CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds) - 1.f, 2.f, 2.f);` and for a big rectangle centered in the view, simply `self.view.bounds`